# I used Agner Fog's vector class but met a serious performance reduction problem when the code was compiled by MSVC

Tags: c++, simd, sse, vector-class-library

I tried to test original SSE/AVX functions compared with [Agner Fog's vector class](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/releases)(My CPU supports both SSE and AVX instructions). Everything was in line with forecast on GNU compiler. Then I switched to MSVC and suddenly found that all vector class options were about 10 times or even more slower than original SSE/AVX functions. My IDE is VS2019/Clion, and the GNU version is 12.2. In addition, I used CMake to conduct compiling. The specific configurations of compilers are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(testSIMD)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external_modules/cmakeFind/")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(USE_VECTORIZE ON)  

if (NOT VECTOR_TYPE)        
    set(VECTOR_TYPE full_vectorize)
endif (NOT VECTOR_TYPE)
if (VECTOR_TYPE STREQUAL "none")
    set(VECTOR_TYPE none)
endif (VECTOR_TYPE STREQUAL "none")
if (VECTOR_TYPE STREQUAL "default")
    set(VECTOR_TYPE default)
endif (VECTOR_TYPE STREQUAL "default")


# Set vectorization flags for a few compilers
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")


find_package(VectorFOG REQUIRED)

#Pushing vector flags onto compiler flags for try compiles
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_SAVE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_SAVE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${VECTOR_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${VECTOR_CXX_FLAGS}")

try_compile(HAVE_FOG_VECTOR_CLASS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fogvectorclasstest.cpp")

if(HAVE_FOG_VECTOR_CLASS)
    message(STATUS "Trying Fog Vector Class -- works")
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_FOG_VECTOR_CLASS)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DMAX_VECTOR_SIZE=512")
    set (FILE_LIST ${FILE_LIST}
            kahan_fog_vector.cpp
            kahan_fog_vector8.cpp)
else()
    message(STATUS "Trying Fog Vector Class -- fails")
endif()


# Set vectorization flags for GNU compiler
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU") # using GCC
    if (USE_VECTORIZE)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -fopenmp-simd -march=native -mtune=native -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized")
    else ()
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -march=native -mtune=native -ffast-math -fno-tree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized")
    endif ()
    if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER "7.4.0")    
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mprefer-vector-width=512")
    endif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER "7.4.0")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang") # using Clang
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -fvectorize -march=native -mtune=native -ffast-math -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /O3")
    add_compile_options(/arch:AVX2)    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Qvec-report:2")
endif ()
```

I was quite confused about this problem. If anyone knows why it happened, please let me know.

Comment: The compiler option `/O3` does not exist in MSVC to my knowledge. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=msvc-170). You also haven't enabled any floating-point optimizations. At the very least, specify `/fp:fast`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed "/O3" to "/Ox", and added "/fp:fast", but it seems still quite slower than GNU. The test result shows that processing an array with 100 million items, GNU will take about 100ms, but VS will take 1000ms.  I can't figure out it.

Comment: Are you *sure* your MSVC builds used `-O2 -fp:fast` or equivalent, rather than still using bad options that it ignores and defaults to unoptimized debug builds?  If you can read asm at all, switch your debugger over to disassembly view and look at your vector loops to see if there's an insane amount of store/reload of each vector variable around each C++ statement.

Comment: If you have a [mcve] of one function that runs much slower with MSVC than GCC, we can have a look on https://godbolt.org/ what asm it compiles to.  (VCL is available on Godbolt)

Comment: I opened disassembly view as you recommended, and there are indeed a lot of store/reload commands.  But I'm sure I added the optimization options in my CMakeLists.txt, like "add_compile_options(/fp:fast)".

Comment: I suspect you’re being screwed by cmake. They declare support of VC++ but the level of support is poor. To test the hypothesis, create a new C++ project with Visual Studio, switch to Release / x64 configuration, change C/C++ / Code Generation / Enable Enhanced Instruction Set setting to AVX2, compile your current C++ code, and check the performance.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I created a new VS project and ran my code in it. Now the VCL function can work efficiently. Although it is still a little bit slower than GNU(about tens of milliseconds slower), I think it is not a big deal anymore.

Comment: @hamster_watcher Good to hear. If you wanna improve performance further, turn on LTCG. C/C++ / Optimization / Whole Program Optimization = "Yes (/GL)", also Linker / Optimization / Link Time Code Generation = "Use Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)".

Comment: @Soonts Thanks for your advice. I really learned a lot from you!